# How to wait for the page to load in HtmlUnit not HtmlUnitDriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, htmlunit, page-load-time

I have a selenium code below which wait for the page to load before the action(click button) is performed. How do I do the same thing with HtmlUnit not HtmlUnitDriver.

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[text()='couple']"))).click();
```

I know there is this line of code below in HtmlUnit:

```
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript();
```

But does it do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

No this is not the same.

`ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable` waits until the element is there/visible and enabled.

`webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(timeoutMillis)` looks only for (async) JavaScript jobs and waits if there are still any that are currently running or waiting in the queue.

Comment: Which line of code I can use in HtmlUnit to emulate selenium "WebDriverWait"?

Comment: At the moment there is no single line of code, maybe you can have a look at the htmlunit-driver impl for hints

Comment: I've used HtmlUnitDriver before, this time around I like to use HtmlUnit. I just want to find a way to manipulate a code to perform the "wait".